# Lucene custom analyzer

Tags: c#, java, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I am making search job site using Lucene, and coped with such problem. I need to search C#, .net so i need to use WhiteSpaceAnalyzer, but if i use it search will be case sensetive.

How can i make this case insensative? Now I see only one solution is to make own Analyzer. But i am new in Lucene, can you please help me with some sample of code for this. I made something that i think must work but it is not. Look

```
public sealed class NewWhitespaceAnalyzer : Analyzer
    {
        public override TokenStream TokenStream(System.String fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
        {
            return new LowerCaseFilter(new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader));
        }

        public override TokenStream ReusableTokenStream(System.String fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
        {
            Tokenizer tokenizer = (Tokenizer)GetPreviousTokenStream();
            if (tokenizer == null)
            {
                tokenizer = new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader);
                SetPreviousTokenStream(tokenizer);
            }
            else
                tokenizer.Reset(reader);
            return tokenizer;
        }
    }
```

If you would see mistake here please correct me.

If you have any other suggestions, you are wlcome.

Thanks for any help,
Dima.

Comment: What doesn't work about this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public sealed class NewWhitespaceAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(System.String fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
    {
        return new LowerCaseFilter(new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader));
    }

    public override TokenStream ReusableTokenStream(System.String fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
    {
        SavedStreams streams = (SavedStreams) GetPreviousTokenStream();
        if (streams == null)
        {
            streams = new SavedStreams();
            SetPreviousTokenStream(streams);
            streams.tokenStream = new WhiteSpaceTokenizer(reader);
            streams.filteredTokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(streams.tokenStream);
        }
        else
        {
            streams.tokenStream.Reset(reader);
        }
        return streams.filteredTokenStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your offer but id doesnot work. It even dont save any document.

Comment: You can check how Tokenizer and TokenFilters are called to get the desired behavior at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/trunk/src/core/Analysis/Standard/StandardAnalyzer.cs and try to write your own Analyzer

Comment: Your code is working with fixing of a little mistake: streams.filteredTokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(streams.filteredTokenStream); replace with streams.filteredTokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(streams.tokenStream);

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 points:

- use `LowerCaseFilter` also in the `ReusableTokenStream` method.
- don't forget to use this custom `Analyzer` in both the query parsing and the document indexing.

enjoy.

Comment: Can you please write example of how to use?